# How to find how an element is currently displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to store the value of the `display` property of an element (`none`, `block`, `inline`...)  in order to restore it later. `element.style.display` returns an empty string if the `display` property is set from a css stylesheet. How do I get the computed value?

The solution can be with jQuery or with another library.

Comment: Can you post your html code what you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#myElemId").css("display");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myDisplay = $('#YourControl').css('display');
```

This would give you the display attribute which u can store

Answer (score 1):

in this case as they said: the display property is stored automatically,

```
var myDisplay = $('#YourControl').css('display');
```

if you want to store additional data in your element,

```
$("#element").data('foo', 52);
```

to restore the data stored in this element

```
var mystoredData = $("#element").data('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you don't have jQuery you can use `getComputedStyle` to detect display property value:

```
window.getComputedStyle(YOUR_DOM_ELEMENT).cssText.split('display: ')[1].split(';')[0]
```

If you have jQuery then use `.css('display')` as others said.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the display property into each element's `.data()`

```
$('.box').on('click',function(){
    displayProp = $(this).css('display');           // read the .css display property
    $(this).data('storedDisplayProp', displayProp); // store it into element data
    $(this).css({display:'none'});                  // modify the .css display
});
```

And retrieve it like:

```
$('#undo').on('click',function(){
  $('.box').each(function(){
    $(this).css({display: $(this).data('storedDisplayProp') }); // read stored data and reset
  });
});
```

#### *[HERE IS A DEMO](http://jsbin.com/alobar/2/edit)*